# Using filedialog - how would I resize image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue with resizing an image using filedialog.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def fileDialog(self):
    self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file")
    self.label = tk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
    self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    self.label.configure(text=os.path.basename(self.filename))

    self.img = Image.open(self.filename)
    self.resized_img = self.img.resize((200, 100))

    self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.resized_img)
    self.display = tk.Label(image=self.photo)
    self.display.grid(row=0)
```

The reason why I am doing this inside of the filedialog function is because I do not know the name of the file that will be chosen until the user clicks on the file. I do `Image.open(self.filename)` because `filename` holds the name of the file that the user clicks on once the file browser opens up. However, I get these errors. I do not want to do `open('car.jpg')` because it may be a different picture this is why I do `open('self.filename')`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "gui.py", line 41, in fileDialog
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.resized_img)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 94, in __init__
image = _get_image_from_kw(kw)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 64, in _get_image_from_kw
return Image.open(source)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2661, in open
prefix = fp.read(16)
   AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
   Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x03A63B70>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
  packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 123, in __del__
   name = self.__photo.name
  AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Is there a reason I am getting this error? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `file=` in `PhotoImage`

```
self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_img)
```

`file=` needs filename, not object `Image()`

effbot.org: [PhotoImage](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: pillow has [ImageFilter and SHARPEN](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFilter.html) but probably there is no ideal method to keep it sharp. Some   
 
scientists build Machine Learning models/tools to resolve it